# How to start a Sony A7iii directly in playback mode?

Tags: sony, image-review, sony-a7ii

I don't like to hear the mechanics of the camera "coming to life" when all I want to do is review photos - often with the lens cap on!  Is it possible to start Sony cameras (e.g. A7iii) in playback mode directly, without first going into "shoot" mode?

Comment: Sounds fair. Did you look into the Sony phone app (Playmemories or something)? Perhpas it can connect to a camera without turning the camera on completely?

Comment: Playmemories is deprecated and replaced by ["Imaging Edge Mobile"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sony.playmemories.mobile&hl=en) and I use it frequently to (download small versions of the photos to my Android phone and then) share photos via WhatsApp. I do not think the app helps in supressing the "coming to life"...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a short one: no.

Comment: Thanks: while this could well be the (unfortunate) case, what's your source / evidence?

Answer (score 1):

According to the ILCE-7M3 Help Guide, [Viewing images on a TV using an HDMI cable](https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1720/v1/en/contents/TP0001653172.html), the camera should enter playback mode when turned on while connected to an active television via HDMI. However, the instructions mention the possibility that the camera might not enter playback mode directly.

Otherwise, the only method of entering playback mode mentioned in the [manual](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/e-mount-body-ilce-7-series/ilce-7m3/manuals) is to press the playback button after the camera has been turned on.